# Encoding in forms doesn't work

Tags: forms, jsp, encoding, utf-8, parameters

I'm passing some information from a JSP to another one. This is the way I call the second JSP page:

```
<form action="second.jsp" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Click</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="El balcón de Andalucía">
</form>
```

And here is the second.jsp page (simplified):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">    
        <title>${param['title']}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the title should be "**El balcón de Andalucía**", but it appears with encoding errors as "**El balcÃ³n de AndalucÃa**", and both pages are specifying that are using utf-8 content.

Where's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: 2 weeks and no reply... how could it be?? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And in the end, I could resolve it.

I just add this line to the file second.jsp, at the top:

```
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
```

That's all.